# Group by error within SELECT statement causing ORA-00979 error code in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
SELECT BOOK.BOOK_NUM AS "Book Number",
       BOOK.BOOK_TITLE AS "Book Title",
       BOOK.BOOK_SUBJECT AS "BOOK SUBJECT",
       ROUND(AVG(BOOK.BOOK_COST),2) as "Subject Avg",
       (BOOK_COST - ROUND(AVG(BOOK.BOOK_COST),2)) AS "COST DIFFERENCE" 
FROM BOOK
GROUP BY BOOK.BOOK_NUM, BOOK.BOOK_TITLE, BOOK.BOOK_SUBJECT
```

However, when I do, I get an error

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

The issue does not seem to occur when I remove:

```
(BOOK_COST - ROUND(AVG(BOOK.BOOK_COST),2)) AS "COST DIFFERENCE"
```

from the `select` statement.

I know a `GROUP BY` statement needs all values from the select statement that aren't functions, and I had thought mine met that requirement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's your dbms?

Comment: @rory.ap What could "ORA" possibly stand for? :)

Comment: What exactly are you expecting the Cost Difference column to return? Remembering  that you are returning the average price per title

Comment: @obe -- My point was, the OP needs to tag the question appropriately.

Comment: You need to include BOOK_COST in your GROUP BY.

Comment: @rory.ap ok I agree with that...

Comment: My apologies, I should have specified, I'm using Oracle as my dbms @rory.ap

Comment: @LordBaconPants I am trying to return the difference between the book's cost relative to the average cost of a book

Comment: @Rene I have tried that, and it does get rid of the error, however the entire column that is displayed are 0's (which is not a correct output, as there should be a difference greater than 0 for most of them)

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause of your error is that you are referencing `BOOK_COST` as a scalar (not within a grouping function), but it is not part of the `GROUP BY` expression.

The obvious "solution" would be to add `BOOK_COST` to the `GROUP BY` list, but I doubt that will give you the answer you want.  In fact, I suspect you already have more columns in the `GROUP BY` than you really want.

It looks like what you want is to:

- Compute the average cost of books within each subject
- List all books and for each, display the difference between that book's cost and the average within its subject

As shown in Gordon's answer, one way to achieve this is by using the windowing version of `AVG()` with an appropriate partition clause.  If my guess about your requirements is correct, then what you want is actually:

```
SELECT BOOK.BOOK_NUM AS "Book Number",
       BOOK.BOOK_TITLE AS "Book Title",
       BOOK.BOOK_SUBJECT AS "BOOK SUBJECT",
       ROUND(AVG(BOOK.BOOK_COST) OVER (PARTITION BY BOOK.BOOK_SUBJECT), 2) as "Subject Avg",
       (BOOK_COST - ROUND(AVG(BOOK.BOOK_COST) OVER (PARTITION BY BOOK.BOOK_SUBJECT), 2)) AS "COST DIFFERENCE" 
FROM BOOK;
```

(You could also use a subquery to avoid writing out the window function twice, but that's not really important for this answer.)

Just for illustration (or if you happen to be on an old version of Oracle), here's a way to do it without a window function:

```
WITH subjects as (
  SELECT book.book_subject, round(avg(book.book_cost),2) as avg_cost
  FROM book
  GROUP BY book.book_subject
)
SELECT
  book.book_num,
  book.book_title,
  book.book_subject,
  subjects.avg_cost,
  book.book_cost - subjects.avg_cost
FROM
  book
JOIN
  subjects ON subject.book_subject = book.book_subject
```

This does one query against the table to find the average cost within each subject, then joins that with the base table so you can calculate the difference for each individual book.

Comment: To give context to the circumstance. I'm in an introductory course, so some of the functions/jargon that you used I have not been instructed in yet, so I apologize in advance that some information might go over my head :/

My requirements for this are:
"Write a query that will display the average cost of books within a given subject and the difference between the books cost and the average cost.  Display the book number, book title, book subject, average cost, and difference.  Sort by book subject."

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for window functions, not aggregation functions:

```
SELECT BOOK.BOOK_NUM AS "Book Number",
       BOOK.BOOK_TITLE AS "Book Title",
       BOOK.BOOK_SUBJECT AS "BOOK SUBJECT",
       ROUND(AVG(BOOK.BOOK_COST) OVER (PARTITION BY BOOK.BOOK_NUM, BOOK.BOOK_TITLE, BOOK.BOOK_SUBJECT), 2) as "Subject Avg",
       (BOOK_COST - ROUND(AVG(BOOK.BOOK_COST) OVER (PARTITION BY BOOK.BOOK_NUM, BOOK.BOOK_TITLE, BOOK.BOOK_SUBJECT), 2)) AS "COST DIFFERENCE" 
FROM BOOK;
```

This keeps all the original rows in your data and adds aggregated columns onto them.

Comment: Except based on the column aliases (and my assumptions about the data), I suspect the window function should probably just use `PARTITION BY BOOK.BOOK_SUBJECT".

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of group by are:

Any attribute in the select part of the query should either be:

- In the group by
- Or as an argument of an aggregate function

In your case,

```
(BOOK_COST - ROUND(AVG(BOOK.BOOK_COST),2)) AS "COST DIFFERENCE"
```

BOOK_COST is not in the group by, nor inside an aggregate function.